# Null Pointer Exception and Swing

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, nullpointerexception, jbutton

Hi I am trying to get the letter x to appear on lines 1-4 and the letter y to appear on lines 7-10. For some reason it works when I put else instead of else if so every line but 1-4 gets "y". It marks the else read and says to delete this token and says Null Pointer Exception and I get an error on line 26, the one with the frame.add

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class ButtonGrid {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JButton[][] grid;
    public ButtonGrid(int width, int length){
        Random r=new Random();
        int w=r.nextInt(13-1)+1;
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length));
        grid=new JButton[width][length];
        Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int y=0;y<length;y++){
            for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
                if (y < 4) {
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton("x");-I am trying to set lines 1-4 to x
                }
                else if (y>7){ 
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton("y");-I am trying to set lines 7-10 to y
                }
                frame.add(grid[x][y]);
                else{ "IT MARKS THIS AS WRONG"
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);``
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonGrid(10,10);

    }
}
```

I think I am doing everything correctly just not sure why eclipse gives me these errors.
Please Help!
Eventually I'm going to be inputting on lines 7-10 but this test wasn't working.
I am doing the board game Stratego in Swing if anybody knows how to help me.

Comment: Please avoid all-CAP statements of frustration. They appear similar to shouting. I've taken the liberty of deleting one such statement from your question.

Comment: Also show your complete error message. Are you really getting a NullPointerException? Or is your code not compiling due to a dangling `else` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve one of your problems: You can only have an `else` block immediately after an `if` block. You're getting an error because you've inserted the statement `frame.add(grid[x][y]);` in between your `else if { ... }` block and your `else { ... }` block.

Answer (score 1):

The line `frame.add(grid[x][y]);` is placed after the `else if`, it will cause compile time error.

```
if (y < 4) {
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton("x");-I am trying to set lines 1-4 to x
                }
                else if (y>7){ 
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton("y");-I am trying to set lines 7-10 to y
                }
                frame.add(grid[x][y]);
                else{ "IT MARKS THIS AS WRONG"
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton(" ");
                }
```

Pls go through [if-else](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted doesn't compile much less generate a NullPointerException since you've got a dangling `else` block:

```
frame.add(grid[x][y]);
else{ // *** this else block is not associated with any if block***
  grid[x][y]=new JButton(" ");
}
```

You'll want to post only the code causing the error, either that or explain the actual error in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

This one line of code was in the wrong place:

```
frame.add(grid[x][y]); // <<<<<<<<<<<<< This line should be here <<<<<<<<<<
```

Here's your whole listing back.  I commented-out some unused code, but the main thing is the line of code above was in the wrong place.

If you have more questions, I'd be glad to coach you.  My email address is: kaydell@yahoo.com.

```
// Not used: import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
// Not Used: import java.util.Random;
// Not Used: import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
// Not used: import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ButtonGrid {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JButton[][] grid;
    public ButtonGrid(int width, int length){
        // Not Used: Random r=new Random();
        // Not Used: int w=r.nextInt(13-1)+1;
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length));
        grid=new JButton[width][length];
        // Not Used: Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int y=0;y<length;y++){
            for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
                if (y < 4) {
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton("x"); // -I am trying to set lines 1-4 to x
                }
                else if (y>7){ 
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton("y"); // -I am trying to set lines 7-10 to y
                }
                else { // "IT MARKS THIS AS WRONG"
                    grid[x][y]=new JButton(" ");
                }
                frame.add(grid[x][y]); // <<<<<<<<<<<<< This line should be here <<<<<<<<<<
            }
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true); // ``
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonGrid(10,10);

    }
}
```